# How can we analyse a function defined on a group?

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, finite-groups

$S_{n}$ is a symmetric group, $X\in S_{n}$,

$f(X): S_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

E.g.

$f(X) = ax_{1}^2+bx_{2}x_{3}+cx_{3}^2$,

$X=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})^{T}$,

$x_{i}\in \{\alpha,\beta, \gamma \}, i=1,2,3$,

$x_{i}\neq x_{j}, \forall i\neq j$,

$a,b,c,\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ are all known quantities.

For $X=(\alpha,\beta, \gamma )^{T}$ and $X^{'}=(\beta, \gamma , \alpha)^{T}$,

is there any viewpoint to analyse the relation between $f(X)$ and $f(X^{'})$ ?

Comment: The function is not clear to me, let us say we take $S_4$ could you write down this function?

Comment: @baharampuri , $n$ is fixed to be 3 in the example, which means $X$ is one of the permutations of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$.

Comment: and $a,b,c,\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I understand you want the orbit of the polynomial $f(X)$ under the action of $S_n$. One can write this with the action of $S_n$ on $\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$. Now if I understood right you want the orbit of the polynomial $ a{x_1}^2+bx_1x_2+c{x_3}^2$, is that right?

Comment: I think you are right. Is there any theory focus on such orbiting? By the way, $f(X)$ is not necessary a polynomial.

Comment: What do you mean $f$ is not a polynomial? In your question it IS a polynomial.

Comment: Hi @baharampuri , it's just a example. In practice, such problems may consist of both polynomials and min/max operators.